# Should we have separate game-maker and game-maker-studio tags for legacy users?

Tags: discussion, tags

I’ve used both Game Maker and briefly Game Maker: Studio. Studio was a complete rewrite of the engine. It has different features, different language standards and syntax, and is considered a separate product. As a result many people still use Game Maker version 8.1 or older which predate Studio. Studio is also a compiled language whereas pre-studio was interpreted. As a result considerations in performance matter a great deal more in one versus the other. Similarly unlike most engines where functions might be removed or added this rewrite changed a large amount of behavior.

I imagine this discussion was had in the past but should we separate the tags and have two?

---

Since an answer has already stated that this is a thing to be done, I am making a list of questions here that should have the studio tag. Since some features do transfer over it might not be necessary to squabble over questions that just happen to be involving Studio; however, as I am primarily a veteran user of Game Maker 8.0 these are questions that are involving features that were either heavily modified and/or added in the Studio rewrite.

- [Doubt about font inclusion (GAMEMAKER)?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/166233/doubt-about-font-inclusion-gamemaker)
- [What is the difference between phy_position_x and x in GameMaker: Studio?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/94145/what-is-the-difference-between-phy-position-x-and-x-in-gamemaker-studio)
- [Gamemaker Studio 2 html5 game sfx influence background music volume](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153869/gamemaker-studio-2-html5-game-sfx-influence-background-music-volume)
- [Why can't I export an APK from my project in Game Maker?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141369/why-cant-i-export-an-apk-from-my-project-in-game-maker)
- [How to make a boss control multiple object spawners in Game Maker Studio 2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152055/how-to-make-a-boss-control-multiple-object-spawners-in-game-maker-studio-2)
- [how to check if an array element is defined? (Game-maker studio)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118147/how-to-check-if-an-array-element-is-defined-game-maker-studio)

I have only been searching for about 5 minutes so don't expect this to be exhaustive as a list.

I do not have enough reputation to create the tag itself (95 rep short) so if someone would please create the new tag by adding it to these questions I will gladly edit the wiki tag accordingly and begin using it elsewhere.

Comment: I see a significiant difference between `game-maker` and `game-maker-studio-2`, Often to the point that I have to put 'GMS2' in the title to ensure I'm talking about the right Studio. There isn't any tag closer related, so I would like a `game-maker-studio` tag at least.

Comment: @Steven you're confusing the versions I'm bringing up here with another issue I'm only partially aware of. You're noting a recent schism between studio version 1 and studio version 2. I'm noting a schism that goes all the way back to around 2015-ish when studio 1 was released. Though if studio 2 has created yet another significant change then I am really fearful for the future of Game Maker's developers. Making that many fundamental changes tends to outright kill usage of a language/engine.

Answer (score 5):

This is equivalent to a versioned tag (e.g., those for D3D9 versus 10 versus 11, et cetera), which we generally only do if there is a *significant* functional difference between the versions of the thing in question.

Based on

> It has different features, different language standards and syntax...

it sounds like that is the case.

However, we also don't really preemptively create tags on the presumption that we'll need them (because we can't, really, they'll just vanish if they're unused).

So in this case, if a collection of questions can be identified (as it seems has been) which are using the existing [game-maker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker) tag but should actually be using a proposed new `game-maker-studio` tag, retagging that collection should be fine.